# How do I make the remote call actually remote?

Tags: webrtc

How do I make an actual remote call?

I've followed the guide: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#4

And gotten their example fully integrated in my application (Angular, TypeScript, multi webcam &etc).

How do I make the remote call actually remote? - I get the idea of a signalling server, but maybe someone can show with basic strings?

---

I found this, but it's not been updated in a while so I'm not sure what's still valid:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found some nice sequence diagrams https://webrtc.org/native-code/native-apis/

### Setup call

[image: Setup call]
<sub>(source: [webrtc.org](https://webrtc.org/assets/images/WebRTCNativeAPIsDocument%20%281%29.png))</sub>

### Receive a Call

[image: Receive a Call]
<sub>(source: [webrtc.org](https://webrtc.org/assets/images/WebRTCNativeAPIsDocument%20%282%29.png))</sub>

### Close Down a Call

[image: Close Down a Call]
<sub>(source: [webrtc.org](https://webrtc.org/assets/images/WebRTCNativeAPIsDocument%20%283%29.png))</sub>